# jQuery find element based on data-attribute value not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html page with the following element:

```
<span class="emojitext ellipsify" dir="ltr" data-reactid=".0.0:$main.4.3.0.0.0.$393382905560@c=1us.$393382905560@c=1us.0.1.1.0.$status">
    How are you?
</span>
```

I'm trying to get it's content with this selector

```
message = $('span.emojitext').find('[data-reactid=".0.0:$main.4.3.0.0.0.$393382905560@c=1us.$393382905560@c=1us.0.1.1.0.$status"]').html();
console.log(message);
```

But it returns `undefined`. At first sight my code looks correct, even by looking at other questions on SO, hence i cannot understand why it's not returning its content which should be `How are you?`

Any clue?

Comment: Use .filter instead of .find?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect as the `span.emojitext` is the element that has the attribute, therefore you don't need to use `find()`:

```
message = $('span.emojitext[data-reactid=".0.0:$main.4.3.0.0.0.$393382905560@c=1us.$393382905560@c=1us.0.1.1.0.$status"]').html();
console.log(message);
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/z9vep4k3/)

Answer (score 0):

Use .attr() instead off find()

```
message = jQuery('span.emojitext').attr('data-reactid','.0.0:$main.4.3.0.0.0.$393382905560@c=1us.$393382905560@c=1us.0.1.1.0.$status').html();
console.log(message);
```

Comment: Calling `.attr()` would ***change*** the value of the attribute. It won't limit what elements are included in the set at all.

Comment: Why would you want to use the setter of `attr()`? The element already has that value. Your logic right now will return a string, which will then mean you get a syntax error when you call `html()`.